# Java ArrayList - item concatenate to another arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Parse the xml and extract the values from the node, below are my existing code.

```
ArrayList mainFamily = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < familyMembers.getLength(); i++) {
        mainFamily.add(familyMembers.item(i).getNodeValue());                
    }
```

output from the above loop

```
[
          , USD, 
          , 60594, 
          , A1, 
          , 20140424, 
        , 
          , USD, 
          , 69203, 
          , B2, 
          , 20150818, 
        ]
```

My question

from the array list i want to concat the value with the following manner and stored into another array list

```
arr[1]-USD60594A1|20140424
arr[2]-USD69203B2|20150818
```

Comment: I surmise that, `familyMembers.item(i).getNodeValue()` gives you  `USD, 60594, A1, 20140424`. If it is so, then you can `split` on `,` and re-arrange the parts and then add it to `mainFamily`.

Comment: What is familyMembers arraylist type?

Comment: @ShaishavJogani thats Node List  NodeList familyMembers;

Comment: What output you are getting here ? `familyMembers.item(i).getNodeValue()`

Comment: @ShaishavJogani : already mention the output from my question

Comment: create custom class `MyClass` with getter/setter of values and then create arraylist of that class `ArrayList<MyClass> mainFamily`. This approach will help you to getParticular data from class

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want:

```
ArrayList mainFamily = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < familyMembers.getLength(); i += 4) {
    String currency = familyMembers.item(i).getNodeValue();
    String price    = familyMembers.item(i+1).getNodeValue();
    String name     = familyMembers.item(i+2).getNodeValue();
    String date     = familyMembers.item(i+3).getNodeValue();

    mainFamily.add(currency + price + name + "|" + date);                
}
```